# Javascript string replace not working

Tags: javascript

So I have a string (a room description) and would like to replace part `<?player>` of it with some new string (`req.session.player`).

Here is the code:

```
var description = "<?player>, you are in a room.";
description.replace("<?player>", req.session.player);
```

I have tested and the `req.session.player` does have string value.

When I do the replace method nothing changes.
NOTE: I have also tried using `/<?player>/` and this did not work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the returned value of the replace method is not assigned:

```
description = description.replace("<?player>", req.session.player);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LEBRK/

Comment: Anyone care to explain this downvote?  I would be interested in knowing how I could improve this answer.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!!

No need for improvement. That was a very good answer.

Answer (score 4):

You must assign your variable to the new altered string, because `replace` doesn't update your variable:

```
var description = "<?player>, you are in a room.";
description = description.replace('<?player>', req.session.player);
```

Moreover, if you want to replace all occurrences of `'<\?player>'` instead of only the first one, then use a regular expression with `g` (global) flag:

```
var description = "<?player>, you are in a room.";
description = description.replace(/<\?player>/g, req.session.player);
```

---

For full information, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace. Some quotes:

> Returns a new string with some or all matches of a `pattern` replaced by a `replacement`.
>
> This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.
>
> To perform a global search and replace, either include the g switch in the regular expression

Answer (score 1):

`replace` method [returns new string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), so you need to assign it to your `description` variable:

```
var description = "<?player>, you are in a room.";

description = description.replace("<?player>", 'Bill'); // description now is "Bill, you are in a room."
```

Comment: Somebody really has a problem with good advice today.  There is no reason to downvote this.

Comment: @KevinBowersox the only reason someone could downvote this is because my answer doesn't add anything new to the previous posts. my apologise, silent downvoter - I didn't refresh the page before answering the question and didn't see that people already answered it.

Comment: I think the issue is that the code didn't implement the recommendation originally.

Comment: @woolstar it's two o'clock in the morning in my city, and I'm almost sleeping. thank you for the pointing out the issue in my answer!